# Symfony strange factories.yml

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I needed to send an email through symfony but in my factories.yml it has something like this

```
all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
  view_cache_manager:
    class: sfViewCacheManager
    param:
      cache_key_use_vary_headers: true
      cache_key_use_host_name:    true
```

And I modify them to something like:

```
all:
   mailer:
    param:
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       smtp.gmail.com
          port:       465
          encryption: ssl
          username: myemail@gmail.com
          password: password
```

will it effect anything ? or what's the original on top does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why remove the previous values? Just merge the two files, like this:

```
all:
  routing:
    class: sfPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
  view_cache_manager:
    class: sfViewCacheManager
    param:
      cache_key_use_vary_headers: true
      cache_key_use_host_name:    true  
  mailer:
    param:
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       smtp.gmail.com
          port:       465
          encryption: ssl
          username: myemail@gmail.com
          password: password
```

otherwise the settings for the routing and the view_cache_manager will be the one you can find on that other `factories.yml` somewhere in `lib/vendor/symfony`